# MySql memory allocation

Tags: mysql, text, size

Anybody knows how MySql allocates memory for "text" and "blob" in case i'm inserting smaller data than the max size of the column ?

For example, What happens when i insert 50K string into a "text" column? Is the entire 65K column allocated ?

Comment: In case of `text` column, it allocates `sizeof(text)` + 2 bytes to store what the size of the text is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TEXT data type comes in four different sizes
*TINYTEXT
*TEXT
*MEDIUMTEXT
*LONGTEXT

differing in the maximum length of values they can store. All are variable-length types, so an individual value requires storage equal to the length (in characters) of the value, plus 1 to 4 bytes to record the length of the value. Trailing spaces are not removed or added for storage or retrieval.

For variable-length (VARCHAR, TEXT) columns, MySQL allocates only the required amount of space for each stored value.

i.e. For Text datatype `Number of characters` + `2 bytes` and has Max length upto 65,535 characters